# The Expected Location Of A Point In A Triangle --- The Centroid

Tags: calculus, geometry

I saw in the solution for a different problem that one had to use the fact that given a random point in a triangle, its expected location is the centroid of said triangle. I was wondering why this was true, and why the expected location is not some other point like the incenter, circumcenter, etc.

Any proof or explanation of why the centroid $C$ of a triangle $ABC$ coincides with the randomly chosen point $P$ within $ABC$ would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start with equilateral triangle, and use the fact centroid is equivariant with respect to all affine linear transformation of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Use vectors:  Let $u = AB$, and $v = AC$, then any point in the triangle can be expressed as

$P = A + t u + s v $

where $t + s \le 1 $

The area of this region, namely $t + s \le 1 $ in the $t, s$ plane is \dfrac{1}{2} $

Hence, the average $P$ is

$ \overline{P} = 2 \displaystyle \int_{t = 0}^{1} \int_{s = 0}^{1 - t} A + t u + s v \ ds \ dt $

This simplifies to

$ \overline{P} = 2 \displaystyle \int_{t = 0}^{1} (1 - t) (A + t u) + \dfrac{1}{2} (1 - t)^2 \ v \ dt $

And finally, this reduces to,

$ \overline{P} = 2 \left( \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2} A + \dfrac{1}{6} u + \dfrac{1}{6} v \right) = A + \dfrac{1}{3} u + \dfrac{1}{3} v$

Substituting $u = B - A$ and $v = C - A$, we get

$ \overline{P} = \dfrac{1}{3} (A + B + C) $

which is by definition the centroid.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\equiv (x_1,y_1)$,$B\equiv (x_2,y_2)$ and $C\equiv (x_3,y_3)$. It is a well known result in co-ordinate geometry that the point $$\left(\frac{\lambda x_1+\mu x_2+\nu x_3}{\lambda+\mu+\nu},\frac{\lambda y_1+\mu y_2+\nu y_3}{\lambda+\mu+\nu}\right)$$ where $\lambda>0,\mu>0,\nu>0$

lies in the interior of $\triangle ABC$ since $$\left(\frac{\lambda x_1+\mu x_2+\nu x_3}{\lambda+\mu+\nu},\frac{\lambda y_1+\mu y_2+\nu y_3}{\lambda+\mu+\nu}\right)\equiv \left(\frac{\lambda x_1+(\mu+\nu)\frac{\mu x_2+\nu x_3}{\mu+\nu}}{\lambda+(\mu+\nu)},\frac{\lambda y_1+(\mu+\nu)\frac{mu y_2+\nu y_3}{\mu+\nu}}{\lambda+(\mu+\nu)}\right)$$and the Centroid is simply a special case of above where $\lambda=\mu=\nu=1$.

Also, if $\lambda=a,\mu=b,\nu=c$ where $a=BC,b=CA,c=AB$ then the above mentioned point is the Incentre of $\triangle ABC$.

So, if your random point $P$ be defined as $$P\equiv \left(\frac{\lambda x_1+\mu x_2+\nu x_3}{\lambda+\mu+\nu},\frac{\lambda y_1+\mu y_2+\nu y_3}{\lambda+\mu+\nu}\right)$$ where $\lambda>0,\mu>0,\nu>0$ then it is bound to lie within the triangle.

In addition if $\lambda=\sin 2A,\mu=\sin 2B,\nu=\sin 2C$, then P is the Circumcentre of the $\triangle ABC$

Further if $\lambda=\tan A,\mu=\tan B,\nu=\tan C$, then P is the Orthocentre of the $\triangle ABC$